# Github Actions "unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials"

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

I have created a github workflow to deploy to GCP. But when it comes to push the docker image to GCP I get this error

```
...
346fddbbb0ff: Waiting
a6fc7a8843ca: Waiting
unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Here is my yaml file :

```
name: Build for Dev

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  GKE_PROJECT: bi-dev
  IMAGE: gcr.io/bi-dev/bot-dev
  DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG: JAVA-${{ github.sha }}

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.event.inputs.commit_sha }}


      - name: Build Docker Image
        run: docker build -t ${{env.IMAGE}} .

      - uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v0.2.0
        with:
          project_id: ${{ env.GKE_PROJECT }}
          service_account_key: ${{ secrets.GKE_KEY }}
          export_default_credentials: true

      - name: Push Docker Image to GCP
        run: |
          gcloud auth configure-docker
          docker tag ${{env.IMAGE}} ${{env.IMAGE}}:${{env.DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG}}
          docker push ${{env.IMAGE}}:${{env.DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG}}
      - name: Update Deployment in GKE
        env:
          GKE_CLUSTER: bots-dev-test
          GKE_DEPLOYMENT: bot-dev
          GKE_CONTAINER: bot-dev
        run: |
          gcloud container clusters get-credentials ${{ env.GKE_CLUSTER }} --zone us-east1-b --project ${{ env.GKE_PROJECT }}
          kubectl set image deployment/$GKE_DEPLOYMENT ${{ env.GKE_CONTAINER }}=${{ env.IMAGE }}:${{ env.TAG }}
          kubectl rollout status deployment/$GKE_DEPLOYMENT
```

**Surprisingly when I manually run docker push it works fine**
Also I am using the similar yaml file to push other projects and they work totally fine. Its just this github action that fails.
Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you verified your user / service account has the permissions to push to the registry?

Comment: Note that the checkout action is available in `v3` and the input you're passing is the default so no need to do that.

Comment: Thank you guys for your input. I discovered that there was an issue with my action secrets which didnt allow me to run the workflow. Its sorted. Thank you again. @rethab

Answer (score 0):

Found out that I missed a step and didnt add the Service Account keys in Secrets for Github actions and that led to the failure of this particular actions.